# Getting values from select elements in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Let's say I have this template:

```
<div *ngFor="let div of divs">
  <select #ref (change)="print(ref)">
    <option *ngFor = "let opt of options">{{opt}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and this component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  divs = ["1", "2", "3"];
  options = ["opt1", "opt2", "opt3"];

  print(value){
    console.log(value.value);
  };
}
```

Now I can get the value of each individual select element whenever a new option is selected. However, with this method I'm creating a `template reference variable` on the select (`#ref`) in the `*ngFor` loop, which means I will have 3 selects with the same reference at the end of the loop. It says the following on the angular.io website:

"Do not define the same variable name more than once in the same template. The runtime value will be unpredictable."

Therefore, I'm assuming it's a bad idea to use this method. My question is if there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, there is need of local varible just for getting selected values :

Just use `(change)="print($event.target.value)"` and `[value]='opt'`

```
<div *ngFor="let div of divs">
  <select (change)="print(div ,$event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor = "let opt of options" [value]='opt'>{{opt}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

print(value_of , value) {
   console.log('value of' , value_of , 'is' , value );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I had completely forgotten about the `$event object`. Thanks!

Comment: @Jesper, Glad to here that :)